# Creating a value matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, data-manipulation

I have a dataset as follow

```
d = {'dist': [100, 200, 200, 400],'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data= d)
```

I would like to create a value matrix around the id

with the calcul : dist(id1) - dist(id2)

```
null  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4
1     |  0  | 100 | 100 | 300 
2     |-100 |  0  |  0  | 200
3     |-100 |  0  |  0  | 200
4     |-300 |-200 |-200 | 0
```

Any advices will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide your attempted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edit) Here's the simplified version via the beauty of numpy:

```
import numpy as np

d = {'dist': [100, 200, 200, 400],'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

a = np.array(d['dist']).reshape(1,-1)
b = np.array(a).reshape(-1,1)

# the solution
print a-b

# [[   0  100  100  300]
#  [-100    0    0  200]
#  [-100    0    0  200]
#  [-300 -200 -200    0]]
```

(Old Answer) You can do it with a little matrix algebra:

```
import numpy as np

d = {'dist': [100, 200, 200, 400],'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

a = np.array(d['dist']).reshape(1,-1)
b = np.array(a).reshape(-1,1)

# some matrix algebra
c = b.dot(a)
e = c/a
f = c/b

# the solution
print f-e

# [[   0  100  100  300]
#  [-100    0    0  200]
#  [-100    0    0  200]
#  [-300 -200 -200    0]]
```

Comment: I see, its equivalent to directly print a- b

Comment: Updated. Score one for numpy. My original answer is what you would need on paper, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with numpy, but you could create the matrix, given the existing data structure, using this mildly complicated dictionary comprehension:

```
matrix = {id: {v: d.get("dist")[i] - d.get("dist")[j] for j, v in enumerate(d.get("id"))} for i, id in enumerate(d.get("id"))}
```

Keys of the matrix are the columns, and keys of each column are the rows. You could probably write this in a much neater fashion, but this a built-ins only answer that conforms to your request.